# Magento Nginx 403 as 404 rewrite to controller 404

Tags: magento, nginx, http-status-code-404

So I am trying to protect sensitive information in Magento and I want `404` to be returned as HTTP status code instead of 403 for restricted pages so that potential threats are not aware that the directory they are accessing even exists.

```
location ^~ /supersecretdirectory/ {
     return 404;
}
```

However what I get is the default Nginx 404. Is there a way to force Nginx use Magento's 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

By Defining CMS No Route Page in Magento admin you can internally rewrite nginx 404 to magento 404 by

```
# retun 404 for sensitive directory
location ^~ /supersecretdirectory/ {
    return 404;
}

# route nginx 404 to Magento 404
error_page 404 /your-CMS-no-route.html;
location = /your-CMS-no-route.html {
    root /path/to/root;
    internal;
}
```

Comment: This is the method I use for my site.